# How to display youtube video using VideoView

Tags: android

I want to know how to display a youtube video in a VideoView :

[image]

and the source is any youtube URL  ??

Comment: why not use youtube player and pass the url to  play the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to embed a YouTube video into your own app, they have sample app so it shouldn't be too difficult if you follow their steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily display any YouTube Video directly in your app using YouTube API from Google. Check this link:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/?hl=it

Here you can find sample applications too:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications